# How to count Combinations

Tags: list, python-2.7, combinations, counting

I was wondering how i would go about counting combinations in a list. To be more precise i have a list that is comprised of smaller lists that are made up of 6 randomly chosen numbers and i want to  count how many times each combinations occurs within the bigger list and then finally display the least occurring combination. So far i tried using Counter() but it seems it can't count lists.
here's an example of what i want to do:

list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,5,16,35,55,22],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[5,25,35,45,55,10],[1,5,16,35,55,22],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[9,16,21,22,23,6],[9,16,21,22,23,6]]

so after counting the combinations it should print the combination [5,25,35,45,55,10]
since it only occurred once in the list

FYI the list is going to randomly generated with around 1 billion combinations stored but given the range of numbers, there's only 175 million possible combinations

FYI 2 i'm extremely new to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you construct the Counter instance you can convert your lists to tuples; the latter are hashable, which is the property an object needs to be able to serve as a key of a dict.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,5,16,35,55,22],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[5,25,35,45,55,10],[1,5,16,35,55,22],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[9,16,21,22,23,6],[9,16,21,22,23,6]]
>>> c = Counter(tuple(e) for e in l)
>>> c
Counter({(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6): 3, (1, 5, 16, 35, 55, 22): 2, (9, 16, 21, 22, 23, 6): 2, (5, 25, 35, 45, 55, 10): 1})
>>> list(c.most_common()[-1][0])
[5, 25, 35, 45, 55, 10]
```

Comment: thank you for quick reply btw is there a way make it count the combinations where order of the numbers matter for example [1,2,3,4,5,6] should be different combo from [6,2,4,5,1,3] cause of the ordering of the numbers

Comment: The method above already does that.  (If you want to ignore order, change 'tuple' to 'frozenset'.)